# IBM Block Chain- Car Lease Demo state database location?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I was working on IBM block chain examples and I deployed car-lease-demo sample on a Linux system. I am not able to understand how the database is storing. I see that there is a location "/var/hyperledger/production" where the database is located but I did not find any location like that. 
         Can anyone explain me how the data is stored and how hyperledger fabric uses the database to store key-value pairs and where is the location of the db where all the data is stored?

Also I would like to know if we can use a different db configuration like NOSQL databases like Neo4j, MongoDB ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation uses LevelDB as the backend store for data and is present on all peer nodes. You can enter the docker container in cli mode and see it for yourself.

Yes, you can change the default DB to any other NoSQL DB. Here's is an example of setting up [CouchDB](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#using-couchdb) with Hyperledger fabric.

As you can see, CouchDB is hosted in a separate container linked to the peer node via an open port (Look at the Docker compose file for details of connection). You can do the same for any other NoSQL DB and use the correct PUT and GET APIs in chain code to access them. But you will have to make sure that data gets replicated in all the DBs in time to maintain the consistency of the Blockchain network

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you help me with the command to check the conents inside the db as I am not sure where is the db file located and how to access it.

Comment: In case you are using CouchDB, you can use their web interface called Fauxton hosted on port 5984. Refer this for the same: http://couchdb.apache.org/fauxton-visual-guide/#intro

Comment: LevelDB does not have a web interface but you can use 3rd party services that give a command line access to the same. A sample 3rd party service is this: https://github.com/0x00A/ldb

Comment: @gonephishing - are you sure we can use `any other nosql database`? or it has to be `couchdb` only

Comment: as far as i remember, it can be any nosql db, but i haven't been following the trends recently